# php exec function taking so much time

Tags: php, node.js

i want to run node js in my php code with **exec** function, but why when i'm running the  **exec** function it's not showing anything. but when i'm running the node js in terminal as usual it running as normal.

> index.js

```
const wa = require('@adiwajshing/baileys');

 async function connecting() {

const init = new wa.WAConnection();

init.connectOptions.logQR = false;
init.logger.level = 'warn';

init.on('qr', qr => {
    console.log(qr)
})

await init.connect();
await init.getChats();

}
connecting().then(res => console.log(res)).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

> php code

```
<?php
exec("node index.js", $res, $code);

echo $res;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `exec()` is using output buffering, which means all output is only returned after it finished.

You could try to use `passthru` instead, which will probably return your output immediately.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php